# default start page for authenticated user in mvc.net core 2.2>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, startup

I have set the default start page in the startup.cs so that only registered users can log in to the website. If the user login details have been saved already (i.e. isauthenticated) I want to redirect to another page other than the default start-up page (i.e. login page). At the moment the login page is displayed whether or not the user is already logged in.

in login.cshtml.cs under OnGetAsync method, I have tried to redirect if the user is IsAuthenticated but it does not seem to redirect.

''startup.cs

```
            services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
             {

  options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity","/Account/Login", "");

           }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

''login.cshtml.cs in
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null){
...
             if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

```
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Members" });
            RedirectToPage("./Members/Home/Index");
            returnUrl = "/Members/Home/Index";
            Redirect("/Members/Home/Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just restrict access to your `HomeController` (assuming you are using the default route template), e.g. using the [Authorize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-2.2) attribute.
In your home controller's `Index` action you could redirect to your custom action.
This should cause unauthenticated users to be redirected to the login action and authenticated users to your custom action